# Replace all occurrences of the substring in string using string slicing

Tags: python, string, substring

I want to replace all substring occurrences in a string, but I wish not to use the replace method. At the moment, experiments have led me to this:

```
def count_substrings_and_replace(string, substring, rpl=None):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    count = 0
    _o = string
    for i in range(0, string_size - substring_size + 1):
        if string[i:i + substring_size] == substring:
            if rpl:
                print(_o[:i] + rpl + _o[i + substring_size:])
            count += 1
    return count, _o

count_substrings_and_replace("aaabaaa", "aaa", "ddd")
```

but I have output like this:

```
dddbaaa
aaabddd
```

not `dddbddd`.

**Update 1:**

I figured out that I can only replace correctly with a string of the same length of substring. For example for `count_substrings_and_replace("aaabaaa", "aaa", "d")` I got output: `(2, 'dbaad')` not `dbd`

**Update 2:**

Issue described in **update 1** did appear because of string comparing relative to the original string (`line 8`) that does not change throughout the process.

Fixed:

```
def count_substrings_and_replace(string, substring, rpl=None):
    string_size = len(string)
    substring_size = len(substring)
    count = 0
    _o = string
    for i in range(0, string_size - substring_size + 1):
        if _o[i:i + substring_size] == substring:
            if rpl:
                _o = _o[:i] + rpl + _o[i + substring_size:]
            count += 1
    return count, _o

count_substrings_and_replace("aaabaaa", "aaa", "d")
```

Output: `(2, dbd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update the value of _o when a match is found, you're only printing out what it'd look like if it was to be replaced. Instead, inside that innermost if statement should be two lines like:

```
_o = _o[:i] + rpl + _o[i + substring_size:]
print(_o)
```

That would print the string every time a match is found and replaced, moving the print statement to run after the for loop would make it only run once the entire string was parsed and replaced appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Just my mistake. I had to pass the value to the variable on each iteration not print:

```
_o = _o[:i] + rpl + _o[i + substring_size:]
```